# Dotnet iot System.Device.Gpio cannot open pin with Output mode

Tags: .net-core, output, gpio, mode, raspberry-pi4

I'm trying opening a pin for PinMode.Output using System.Device.Gpio on .NET Core and then want to write a value for this pin but I get an exception, which says that pin is opened not for Output mode and writing is not allowed for that.

My code is:

```
    [HttpGet("{pinNumber}/{inputPinValue}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SetPin(int pinNumber, string inputPinValue)
    {
        PinValue value = inputPinValue == "high" ? PinValue.High : PinValue.Low;

        var controller = new GpioController(PinNumberingScheme.Logical, new GpioDriverMock());
            controller.OpenPin(pinNumber, PinMode.Output);
            controller.Write(pinNumber, value);


        var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject($"Pin value is {value}");

        return StatusCode(200, result);
    }
```

The exception is:
System.InvalidOperationException: Can not write to a pin that is not set to Output mode.
at System.Device.Gpio.GpioController.Write(Int32 pinNumber, PinValue value)

I have also the seperate method that just read a pin value and that is working correctly (pin mode is Input as a default mode)

Just for explanation:

GpioDriverMock - is a class for mocking a driver to be able to debug app on Win 10. The target environment of this app is Raspberry Pi with Docker, so I remove creating this mock class instance before I carry over the app to Raspberry.

When I'm running this app on targeted Raspberry it also doesn't work and returns the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

Does this sample work for you? If not, then something else is wrong.

https://github.com/dotnet/iot/blob/master/samples/led-blink/Program.cs

Does your code work when not run in a container? In some cases, containers need to be run in privileged mode to use GPIO or other pins.

Comment: Unfortunetally not. I already tried this out and didn't work. Regarding running outside container -  before I carried over it to container I debuged this locally on my PC (sending request by Postman to localhost) and the exception was the same.